# I have an error when implementing the my function in R

Tags: r, error-handling, statistics

**after running this function I have this Error:**
*Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Energy, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2642*

```
library(dplyr)

shower = read.csv2("Shower_data.csv")
survey = read.csv2("Survey.csv")
uniteData<- dplyr::inner_join(shower, survey, by=c("Hh_ID" = "Hh_ID"))

dataEng <- data.frame(uniteData$Hh_ID, uniteData$Volume, uniteData$Avgtemperature, uniteData$beobachten)
colnames(dataEng) <-c('ID','Volume', 'AvgTemperature', 'beobachten')
#data$Energy <- with(data, data$Volume*(data$AvgTemperature-12)/0.65*4.185/3600)


calculateEnergy <- function(temperature, volume){
  energy = c(volume * (temperature-12)/0.65*4.185/3600)
  return(energy)
}


oft <- dataEng %>% dplyr::filter(beobachten == "Oft")

eherOft <-dataEng %>% dplyr::filter(beobachten == "Eher oft")

selten <-dataEng %>% dplyr::filter(beobachten == "Selten")

eherSelten <-dataEng %>% dplyr::filter(beobachten == "Eher selten")

oft$Energy<- calculateEnergy(oft$Avgtemperature, oft$Volume)
```

*Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Energy, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2642*

Comment: I know that the problem is in my function:    calculateEnergy <- function(temperature, volume){
  energy = c(volume * (temperature-12)/0.65*4.185/3600)
  return(energy)
}

Comment: Have you checked with `str(oft)` that you are calling `calculateEnergy` with numeric`? why is there a `c(...)` in the function?

Comment: `oft$Energy<- calculateEnergy(oft$Avgtemperature, oft$Volume)` shouldn't that be "AvgTemperature" with a capital "T" instead of a small "t"?

Comment: Thanks, you where right. The problem of overwhelming code doesn't allow me to find small mistakes... Should be counted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a mistake of your Variable Names: `AvgTemperature` -> T instead of t

Answer (score 1):

As we found in the comment section, the problem was a letter, that needed to be capitalized in the call `oft$Energy<- calculateEnergy(oft$Avgtemperature, oft$Volume)`. The best solution to that is to use the help of a good editor, like the one in RStudio, that will help for example through auto completion. Also, in RStudio it takes only one click on a button to erase all old variables, so you don't mess around with an old variable, that has long lost it's meaning but is still in the namespace.

Use RStudio, learn RStudio and it will help you avoid this kind of error.